# MSSQL full text search with sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, full-text-search

I am using Entity Framework v6.3 and calling `DbSet.SqlQuery` to query a table for a country. Full text indexing is enabled for the table and column. The SQL emitted is below:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM tblBaseGeos WHERE Contains(Name, @p0)',N'@p0 nvarchar(13)',@p0=N'United States'
```

This gives me the error: `Syntax error near 'States' in the full-text search condition 'United States'.`

Ive read how to do it normally:

```
SELECT * FROM tblBaseGeos WHERE Contains(Name, '"United States"')
```

That works, but I am having trouble with the double quotes with `sp_executesql`.  How can I fix the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your search phrase with double quotes and add 2 symbols to the length of your nvarchar parameter. Code below works fine

```
exec sp_executesql 
 N'SELECT * FROM tblBaseGeos WHERE Contains(Name, @p0)',N'@p0 nvarchar(15)',
  @p0=N'"United States"'
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I was doing and it failed.  Looking at yours, I realized I forgot to increase the nvarchar length during testing...